# Comparing Thymeleaf fragments and Apache Tiles?

Tags: java, fragment, tiles, thymeleaf, tiles2

Has anyone had experience with Thymeleaf fragments for page layout in a big project? Tiles look cleaner to me compared to fragments.

I would appreciate your inputs.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case you are interested, you may have a look at the new article at thymeleaf.org describing layout techniques available in Thymeleaf. The article can be found here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/layouts.html

Also, have a look at this comment as well: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/is-it-worth-upgrading-to-thymeleaf-21.html?showComment=1383802606153#c6439427685119794598

In above comments, you can find out that custom technique is used and the project is contains ~30 views. Is this a big project? I think it is a matter of definition what is big. I think you should try the solution and find the one that fits best you, the team, the project etc.